# Converting a Struts submit button to a link

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, twitter-bootstrap, struts

I am currently working on a simple project that integrates Spring 3.2 and Struts 1.2. I am using Bootstrap for most of my styling, but I have come across a problem. Bootstrap gives me this pre-made container table with links http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups it is under Linked Items.

My goal is to map a link with an action, without loosing the styling that bootstrap has provided.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<html:link action="/view">
        <html:submit>
            <a class="list-group-item"><strong>View</strong> all employees</a>
        </html:submit>
</html:link>
```

Although this works, it makes a weird link/button.

Any ideas or alternative methods of solving my problem would be highly appreciated!

**EDIT**

So all I needed to do was change the styling to my `html:link` like Dave Newton had mentioned. Struts has a specific attribute for applying a CSS stylesheet class to its tags. This attribute is called `styleClass`, once I added it to my code it worked:

```
<html:link action="/view" styleClass="list-group-item" >
    <strong>View</strong> all employees
</html:link>
```

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I don't really know what you're asking. A submit button makes zero sense without a form. An `html:link` makes a link, but so does an `<a>` tag; nesting them is almost certainly not what you want. Why aren't you just styling `<html:link>`? And I hope it's not a *new* project.

Comment: Well I need to submit the action to my struts xml file and I am not sure how to do this if not by a submit button.

Comment: Also what do you mean by styling my <html:link> tag?

Comment: Did you try to submit it with javascript?

Comment: I have tried a couple of variations of javascript including the onclick event. However, I get errors stating that there is no form on the page.

Comment: @Roman Can you give me an example of how to achieve this

Comment: @Dave Newton this is not a new project by the way.

Comment: You don't "submit an action", you submit a *form*. If there's no form, you don't submit, you *link*, like any other HTML link. By styling the `<html:link>` tag, I mean use `cssStyle` to provide... CSS style. It's a link; I don't really see the issue yet. I don't understand why you'd even consider JavaScript if you're just linking to another page?

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the response I was just not seeing the obvious. I was all caught up in trying to submit an action into struts that I did not take into consideration that the struts tag library can have styling as well.

Comment: @DaveNewton, to answer your question I am making a call to the database each time the link is clicked. So I was not just linking to another page. That is why I wanted that action mapped into my struts xml file.

Comment: @jjcode "Pages" in a Struts app, whether Struts 1 or Struts2, *are* actions (or *should* be in a well-crafted web app)--the terms are interchangeable.

Comment: I see sorry for the misunderstanding I am still quite new to Struts. Anyways thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)